# object.prototype.constructor = X (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following javascript code-snippet is seen in Source Code of Node.js API 'Buffer'. However the **'Buffer'** (constructor?) has not been initialized anywhere in the code.

```
class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array {
  constructor(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    super(arg1, arg2, arg3);
  }
}
FastBuffer.prototype.constructor = Buffer;
Buffer.prototype = FastBuffer.prototype;
```

Comment: `Buffer` is a global in Node.

Comment: @Ryan where could we see the constructor for the Buffer

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8f52ccc828c26aee8fe78c82a8a23fabd21918b7/lib/buffer.js#L161 (it is actually defined in the same file anyway.)